# The Dirty Dozen Triad Test and how it's scored

Tags: normal-distribution, psychometrics

I'm trying to figure out some statistics to do with a test for a personality disorder called '**The Dark Triad**'. The test is called the '**Dark Triad Dirty Dozen**' (DTDD).

The test is reported in 'Psychology Today' at https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/fulfillment-any-age/201301/shedding-light-psychology-s-dark-triad However, I find the scoring system that the author in Psychology Today claims should be used is unconvincing. I quote:

> Among the college students tested in a later, validational, study Webster and Jonason (2013) report an average of about 36, with most people scoring between 33 and 39, meaning that anyone scoring upwards of 45 would be considered very high on the Dark Triad total.

Not being a mathematician and having spent ages reading documents and trying to find a summary of the scoring system and also unable to contact the original author of the study (no contact email) or Psychology Today (again, couldn't find a contact form) I'm hoping that someone can cast some light on the matter.

As I understand it a couple of standard deviations minimum (distance from the centre of the bell curve) would be required to say that someone is an outlier or 'very high' on the Dark Triad . That's about as far as my maths takes me. I have no idea where she got her figures of 33 - 39, or her figure of 45 as 'very high'. I can see that 12 questions each with a mean of 2.92 gives 35.04, but that's not 36 ...

http://peterjonason.com/uploads/WebsterJonasonIRT.pdf

Table 3, Sample 2 (N = 544; 7-point scale i.e. each question gets scored from 1 - 7), 12 questions

**DTDD test**

Mean 2.92 (presumably the mean for each question)

SD 1.07 (presumably the standard deviation for each question)

Reliability .87

MIC .36

Total 43.04 (no idea where this number comes from)

Per Item 3.59 (total divided by 12)

Comment: Hey WotNot, welcome to CV. I would start with writing the corresponding author, and (respectfully) expressing your interest in how they scored their data, since you can't find enough details in the article. Corresponding authors are often friendly to this kind of contact, sometimes even years after the data of publication.